# Search for a particular text in a string - Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

```
/google/gmail/inbox
 /google/drive/map
 /google/apps
 /yahoo/news/cricket
 /yahoo/mail/
 /yahoo/sports
 /wiki/ind/jack
 /wiki/us/jil
```

I need to get the required page groups. If i search for page group starting with 'google' using hive query, I need to get the data of the first 3 rows.

```
/google/gmail/inbox
 /google/drive/map
 /google/apps
```

In this way I need to get the data based on page group.

---

I searched for the string using like function.

```
select * from table where field like '%/google/%';
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like you want page group.  Which may be google, but it seems like it could also be yahoo perhaps.  If you want to extract the page group by search engine you can use a regular expression.  You can place multiple websites in the (page1|page2|...|pageN).

```
Select column from table
where column rlike '.*(google|yahoo).*'
```

Output:

```
/google/gmail/inbox
/google/drive/map
/google/apps
```

You may want to create a new column that has the search engine name it or landing page.  It seems like the first place in the path is the landing page.  You can extact the landing page in this fashion:

```
select * from
    (Select column
    , regexp_extract('^(\\/[a-zA-Z]*\\/)',1) as landing_page
    from table) a
  where landing page in ('google','yahoo',...,'bing')
  ;
```

Output:

```
column                   new column
/google/gmail/inbox      /google/
/google/drive/map        /google/
/google/apps             /google/
/yahoo/news/cricket      /yahoo/
/yahoo/mail/             /yahoo/
/yahoo/sports            /yahoo/
/bing/meats/delisandwich /bing/
/bing/maps/delis         /bing/
```

If you don't want /google/ and prefer just google then do:

```
regexp_extract('^\\/([a-zA-Z]*)\\/',1) as landing_page
```

Now I am assuming that the landing page comes first in the paths you describe.

Answer (score 5):

The question is a bit ambiguous, but I believe you are trying to search for the word `google` in the string and return the rows which contain the word `google` in the string.

Suppose you have the following table:

```
create table test (val string);
```

And it contain the following records:

```
hive> select * from test;
/google/gmail/inbox
/google/drive/map
/yahoo/mail/
```

You can select the rows which contains the string `google` using the below query:

```
select val from test
where instr(val, 'google') = 2;
```

This gives the result:

```
/google/gmail/inbox
/google/drive/map
```

`instr` gives the position of the string you searched for. In this case, the position of `google` is 2. If you are trying to get all the rows which contains `google` anywhere, then you can use:

```
select val from test
where instr(val, 'google') != 0;
```

You can read about the various Hive string functions from the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions).

Comment: We cant hard code the positions. Used Like operator.

Comment: @Krishna if you're using `LIKE` operator, then you get all the rows in which 'google' is present. My understanding was that you needed rows in which 'google' was present in a particular position. Also, I believe `LIKE` is not so optimized when it comes to performance